# Why does my code create to much threads (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread)

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I try to check if an element is in a string by looking parallel through the list by splitting it:

`public class ParallelSearchComment extends RecursiveTask  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
int lo; 
int hi; 
String com;
String query;
int T;

ParallelSearchComment(String c, int l, int h, String q, int Treshold){
    com=c;
    lo=l;
    hi=h;
    query=q;
    T=Treshold;
}

private int findMiddle(String text){ // Only split at whitespace chars (or some words would be missed) 

    int middle = lo + ((hi - lo)/2);
    int i= middle;                                                            
    for (i = middle; i != hi && com.charAt(middle) != ' ' && i-middle <= query.length()+1; i++){

    }  
    middle = i;
    return middle;
}

@Override
protected Boolean compute() {
    int middle = findMiddle(com);
    if (hi - lo < T || hi-middle <= query.length()) {//hi-middle <= query.length()
        return com.substring(lo, hi).contains(query);
    } else {

        ParallelSearchComment left = new ParallelSearchComment(com, lo, middle, query, T);
        ParallelSearchComment right = new ParallelSearchComment(com, middle, hi, query, T);

        left.fork();
        boolean resRight = right.compute();
        boolean resLeft = left.join();

        return resRight || resLeft;
    }

}

static boolean ParallelSearchComment(String c, String query, int T,int p) {
    final ForkJoinPool fjPool = new ForkJoinPool(p);
    ParallelSearchComment t = new ParallelSearchComment(c, 0, c.length(), query, T);
    return fjPool.invoke(t);
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are creating a new `ForkJoinPool` instance each time you call `ParallelSearchComment`.  Instead you should create one `ForkJoinPool` and use throughout the application.

Comment: This solution resolved my problem, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Since your snippet doesn't show how `static boolean ParallelSearchComment` is being invoked, I'll assume that it's being used to initialize your search. Also, I'll assume that you've triggered the search only once from your `main`.

With that, it's quite likely that the parallelism value, or `p`, that you're passing in is higher than your current JVM heap can handle. See what happens when you reduce it to 5 or 10.

Comment: I thought the same as you but after changing the value of p and my threshold same problem happend. The solution of Stephan C above resolved my problem

Comment: In that case, you should mark his answer as accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Also, please update the code snippet to show how `static boolean ParallelSearchComment` is being invoked multiple times.